# How to create a regex to check whether a set of words exists in a given string?

Tags: regex

How can I write a regex to check if a set of words exist in a given string?

For example, I would like to check if a domain name contains "yahoo.com" at the end of it.

'answers.yahoo.com', would be valid.
'yahoo.com.answers', would be wrong. 'yahoo.com' must come in the end.

I got a hint from somewhere that it might be something like this.

```
"/^[^yahoo.com]$/"
```

But I am totally new to regex. So please help with this one, then I can learn further.

Comment: If you want to check for a particular sequence, one regex will be enough. If you genuinely want to check for all of a set of words, you'll need to loop over the corresponding regexes. Your question needs clarification, though. Also, using regex to check for a valid domain name seems futile -- the only sane way to do that is a DNS query.

Comment: In what language you want this regex?

Comment: The regex `^(yahoo\.com)$` checks for start of line `^` followed by the literal string `yahoo.com` (the parentheses are superfluous in this case; I put them in just to point out that these should be round parentheses, not square brackets) and end if line `$`. If you want to check for this string with anything before it, drop the start of line anchor `^`. Note that if you do, the regex will also match e.g. `aaayahoo.com`. But until your question is understandable, let's leave it at this.

Comment: Irrespective of which language you use this regex: `\.yahoo\.com$` will work for you making sure any `foo.yahoo.com` or `bar.yahoo.com` is matched.

Comment: Any subdomain of `yahoo.com`, yes, but not the top-level domain. Something like `(^|\.)yahoo\.com$` should work, but this depends on which regex flavor (i.e. tool) you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking regex questions, always specify the language or application, too!

From your history it looks like JavaScript / jQuery is most likely.

Anyway, to test that a string ends in "yahoo.com" use `/.*yahoo\.com$/i`

In JS code:

```
if (/.*yahoo\.com$/i.test (YOUR_STR) ) {
    //-- It's good.
}
```

To test whether a set of words has at least one match, use:

```
/word_one|word_two|word_three/
```

To limit matches to just the most-common, legal sub-domains, ending with "yahoo.com", use:

```
/^(\w+\.)+yahoo\.com$/
```

(As a crude, first pass)

For other permutations, please clarify the question.

Comment: The beginning `.*` is superfluous.

Comment: @tripleee, it is superfluous *for the moment*, when just testing a string.  But it's a good habit that doesn't hurt, and when the regex evolves to extraction or replacement, something like that is often needed.

Comment: I tried this, `/^([A-Za-z0-9]+.)+yahoo.com$/` It is almost correct. But I don't understand, it is not detecting error in something like: `a%v.ab.yahoo.com`. Now it will detect error in `a%.ab.yahoo.com`. But if I add another character after that %, it will pass that string as correct ! what's going on in that regex??

Comment: @ShantanuD, that requirement was not in the question!  Nevertheless, see my updated answer.  You need to escape the `.`s like so: `\.`.